# How to compare two Excel files with Microsoft 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

As file conflicts can easily occur in the new and shiny world of SharePoint/OneDrive-based Excel 365 it is important to be able to compare different versions of a file.

All info I found online talks about older versions of Excel.

How can I compare two Excel files in Excel 365? I need to see a useable overview of all their differences, ideally with a way to merge them.

Answer (score 8):

You may compare two Excel spreadsheets using the ribbon entry
*Inquire > Compare Files*.
You need to have two workbooks open in Excel to run this command.

For more information about the command, see the Microsoft article
[What you can do with Spreadsheet Inquire](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42?ns=excel&version=19&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

The Inquire pane is not enabled by default in Excel.

To
[enable Inquire](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-the-inquire-add-in-6bc668e2-f3c6-4729-8ce1-75ea20aa9d90):

- Enter *File > Options > Add ins*
- Set "Manage" to "COM Add-ins"
- Click Go
- Place a check-mark next to "Inquire"
- Click OK.

Comment: wow this is a fantastic feature, I wish I'd learnt of this much sooner than now

Comment: Sadly this seems not to be included in my "Microsoft 365 Apps for Business" although I would have assumed that is the "enterprise editions" your second link mentions as having it. I will leave the question open for now, maybe there are more options. Thank you very much already!

Answer (score 1):

The steps shown here are wrong - there is no Inquire option in 365!
Enter File > Options > Add ins
Set "Manage" to "COM Add-ins"
Click Go
Place a check-mark next to "Inquire"
Click OK.

Comment: Steps where? In other answer? Your answer needs to be more detailed. Link to your reference. Perhaps show a screenshot of the checkmark you're describing.